# What is the cause of my post being deleted?

Tags: support, moderation, specific-answer

A few moments ago I realized that my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67302912/6622587 was deleted by the moderator [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-fabre). And so far I have not received information about the cause of that deletion and I do not see anything wrong with my post.

Comment: As you were probably aware that this wasn't supposed to be deleted, I think you could've instead contacted the moderators directly. Ironically, this question should probably be closed/deleted for being yet another *"Why was my question/answer closed/deleted?"*

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your post appeared as a duplicate answer in moderator tools. Note that I usually use Sam's userscript (delete+comment) which adds a "don't post duplicate answers" comment while deleting. But I can't have those scripts running on my corporate computer (yes, moderating from work, this is bad, I know).

But in the meantime, you had removed the other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67302885/6451573 that you "defaced" but the system had time to detect a perfect duplicate). The tools showed the other answer as deleted but I was a bit quick and I assumed that the other answer was bad so someone deleted it, so that answer also deserved it => *wrong*.

I've undeleted it now. There's nothing wrong with what you globally did.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I had several windows open and when I copied my answer I did it in the wrong window, in a few moments after my error (less than 1 minute) I corrected it. I do not understand how it can be kept as a duplicate answer if the time in which both were active was minimal.

Comment: the system is swift :)

Comment: Okay, but the system should also show that the one who deleted the other post was me. :-)

Comment: that doesn't appear in our tools. Besides, we see a lot of those: OP posts 3 answers, gets downvotes on some, so they delete it, but leave the others. I though that was this case. Sorry! I should have checked who posted too...

Comment: okay, i get your point. Only that it is the first time that I have been deleted a post and I already had this type of errors where I first deleted the inappropriate post and then published the correct post but today I deleted the inappropriate post after the correct post that launches that false positive. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: your case is a very rare one. Most people we catch doing that are newbies copying/pasting the same blurb in several questions hoping to get 1 stray upvote without too much effort.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that type of action and have reported it several times.

Comment: keep doing so. the system only detects _exact_ copies. For the rest we need actual people.

Comment: Also I did not see any comment that indicates that it was closed for publishing the same answer multiple times (which usually appears in this type of case) so I did not relate it to that action. Thanks.

Comment: *the system is swift :)* I knew it wouldn't be C++, but Swift is still a surprise.

Comment: yeah, I think that's intentional. I've seen 3k users posting duplicate answers. So where is the limit?

Comment: but noone has the right to post duplicate answers. I would delete duplicate answers from Jon Skeet if he did that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Jon Skeet does not post duplicate answers, we "mere mortals" just fail to see the differences in such cases because we're not on the same plane of existence :D